# unable to use 'class' keyword in ECMA6

Tags: javascript

I tried running class in ECMA2015 but gets below error

```
class Task {
constructor(name)
{ 
this.name=name;
this.completed = false;    
};
}
```

I get below error

```
class Task {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word}
```

**note** am using latest node version 0.12.14 and also i tried using

```
node --harmony <myfilename> 
node --harmony_modules <myfilename>
```

etc but nothing helped.Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [latest node.js version is v6](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).  Your version v0.12.14 is old and thus doesn't support many ES6 features.

See [this table](http://node.green/#class) and [this table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for feature support in different node.js versions.  Full support for the `class` keyword appears mostly in v4 with full implementation in v5.